# Configuring activity types in a Microsoft teams app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have sideloaded a teams app with an activity type, so that I could I could use [the activity feed graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification). However, when I send a `teams/<teamId>/sendActivityNotification` request, I get 501 "Not Implemented". There are no specifics in the response.

```
{  "error": {    "code": "NotImplemented",    "message": "Failed to process request.",    "innerError": {      "date": "2021-04-16T07:48:31",      "request-id": "bd92c3a5-9ec5-49a1-a2d5-057f7dd3c182",      "client-request-id": "bd92c3a5-9ec5-49a1-a2d5-057f7dd3c182"    }  }}
```

I think I may be missing something about how graph API integrates with teams apps.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "id": "<APP_ID>",
  "version": "1.0",
  "packageName": "com.nikita",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Nikita Cool Dude",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com"
  },
  "name": {
    "full": "MMM service test",
    "short": "MMM service test"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "description": {
    "full": "Packages mmm activity types.",
    "short": "Packages mmm activity types."
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "mmm-small.png",
    "color": "mmm-small.png"
  },
  "activities": {
    "activityTypes": [
      {
        "type": "mmmChannelCreated",
        "description": "New channel is created for an mmm event",
        "templateText": "New <priority> <cfs> event"
      }
    ]
  },
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "<APP_ID>",
      "scopes": ["team"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that I am adding a connector I'm not using. Otherwise I get `Error while reading manifest.json: "configurableTabs, staticTabs, bots, connectors, or composeExtensions" is required`  error when sideloading the app. The app id is created through portal.azure.com.

Below is the request payload, in case that is relevant. I based it very closely on examples in the graph API documentation.

```
{
    "topic": {
        "source": "entityUrl",
        "value": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<teamId>/channels/<channelId>",
    },
    "activityType": "mmmChannelCreated",
    "previewText": {
        "content": "New important event!"
    },
    "templateParameters": [
        {
            "name": "priority",
            "value": "P1"
        },
        {
            "name": "cfs",
            "value": "Armed Robbery"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Could you please confirm are you adding the required permissions as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest webApplicationInfo section is missing. The Teams app manifest must have the Azure AD app ID added to the webApplicationInfo section. Follow the requirements provided in [documetation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#requirements-for-using-the-activity-feed-notification-apis) to use sendActivityNotification.